# Save JavaScript Promise for future use

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working on Node.js to build the server side RESTApi. Node works fine when I tested by myself. But when it is really out there it could still facing the overflow problems. When there are lots of requests, say there are more than 5 child_process (spawn) working at the same time, each process is taking longer time, basically slow down everything.

My idea is to check if the current process is below a certain limit (like, limit to 3 processes at a time), if it exceed the limit, I save the requests into an array, and whenever the current processes is below the limit, I use .shift() to pop the oldest one in the array and process it.

However when it comes to Promises, it becomes difficult as I don't know if we can store a Promise into an array or not, or whether I should simply let the process pause for seconds which I don't think it is a good idea.

What is the normal way if you want to hold a promise and return the promise to client in future?

Sorry if I didn't state this clear. Here is a summary of my doubts:
1. Can we save a promise for future use? 
2. Do we save them in arrays?
3. Shall I use other methods to hold the promise, like, using sleep() or simply a while loop to wait until this process is proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: Promise is already inherently a construct that represents a future value. At any point after it's creation, when you call `then(cb)` on it, it will provide you with the value.

Comment: Would it be helpful if I use loadash?

Comment: Have you considered using the `promise-queue` package with your processes?

Comment: Yes, promises a plain values that can be passed around like any other.

Comment: Sounds like you need a more powerful server, or find and fix the performance bottleneck. Just queuing request is usually not going to help - those queues eventually will overflow as well. And administrating them requires additional processing power and memory, so you're usually better of serving them as quick as possible.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! But I'm using it because from my server I still use rest api to connect Google apis and for Google there are limitations in request and data amount. I guess if the queues eventually overflows again I will return to client a 400(or related) reject response and tell them to slow down their request frequency.

Comment: @CharlesZha Well queuing the API requests themselves is OK, but I don't see what this has to do with the slow child processes you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> say there are more than 5 child_process (spawn) working at the same time, each process is taking longer time, basically slow down everything.

In a real world deployment - you would not handle CPU intensive tasks with child tasks this way - you would use a sane concurrent data structure (like a queue on mqtt or a database) and distribute the work to workers you deploy who would then send it back to the server.

The reason is that the server can always go down - and you want to guard against partial work.

> My idea is to check if the current process is below a certain limit (like, limit to 3 processes at a time), if it exceed the limit, I save the requests into an array, and whenever the current processes is below the limit, I use .shift() to pop the oldest one in the array and process it.

Here is code that does that, **I beg you to read the first point** and *not* use that code in production but instead limit that at your deployment (for example if you use AWS to limit the scale to 3 instances):

```
// lifted from my bluebird-api project
function throttle(fn, concurrency = 20, Promise) {
    // create an array of workers as resolved promises
    const workers = Array(concurrency).fill(Promise.resolve());
    const work = []; // pending work
    return function (...args) {
        // when there is work, pull the next worker
        const worker = workers.pop();
        if (worker === undefined) { // if there is no pending worker
            let resolve, reject;
            // store the promise for the result
            const promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
                resolve = res; 
                reject = rej;
            });
            // and add it to the queue
            work.unshift({ args, resolve, reject, promise });
            return promise;
        }
        // after the worker is ready, call the function
        worker = worker.then(() => (fn(...args), null));
        worker.then(function pump() {
            if (work.length) { // after you're ready
                const {resolve, reject, args} = work.pop();
                // continue draining the queue
                worker = worker.then(() => fn(...args)).then(resolve, reject).then(pump);
            } else { // or declare ready
                workers.push(worker);
            }
            return null;
        });
        return worker;
    }
}
```

The code is lifted from [bluebird-api](https://github.com/benjamingr/bluebird-api/blob/master/promiseFns/util.js) which is still WIP.

> What is the normal way if you want to hold a promise and return the promise to client in future?

Yes, it is entirely a supported case - and it doesn't leak memory and is safe (in modern promise implementation). Although again - this is an XY issue - you should not distribute work that way on a Node server.

When you implement the correct solution (queueing and offloading to different services) you can create a queue of promises where you return a promise and resolve it later when the queue is ready.

Comment: So in real world, the "child process" is usually in a different server instance?

Comment: I'm actually using child_process to run python in the back. Are there better ways to do that?

Comment: In the "real world" you'd typically do all this in containers and run python would run in a different container feeding from a queue - that way you can scale the number of python process instances "elastically".

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Can we save a promise for future use? 2. Do we save them in arrays?

You can store a Promise in an array, that is part of the beauty of promises that they don't need to be evaluated until needed.

> 3. Shall I use other methods to hold the promise, like, using sleep() or simply a while loop to wait until this process is proceed?

Nothing wrong with using sleep. Do not loop that is inefficient.

*EDIT*

@Bergi says in comments that even in a Promise `sleep` should not be used either.

Comment: `sleep` sounds like a synchronous blocking method, which would be just as wrong as a loop

Comment: @Bergi I thought OP meant sleep in the promise

Comment: "in the promise" does not mean "in the background". You shouldn't sleep at all.